# Spring Boot + Kotlin annotation error(s)

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-annotations, spring-webflux

I have a Spring Boot `2.0.0.M2` (with WebFlux) application written in Kotlin.

I'm used to define/declare "annotations" for test cases in order to avoid some boilerplate configuration; something like:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy
import java.lang.annotation.Target
...

@Inherited
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient // TODO: FTW this really does?!
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
//@kotlin.annotation.Target(AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
//@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = arrayOf("default", "test"))
@ContextConfiguration(classes = arrayOf(Application::class))
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
annotation class SpringWebFluxTest
```

...then in my tests I use it like:

```
@SpringWebFluxTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
class PersonWorkflowTest {
  private lateinit var client: WebTestClient
  ...
```

The **issue is** that I can't achieve the same using the annotations provided by Kotlin:

```
@kotlin.annotation.Target(AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
```

I'm getting a `this annotation is not applicable to target 'class'` inside `PersonWorkflowTest`. If I use the Java ones everything is fine, but on the other hand I get these warnings ― which what I'm really trying to get rid of :)

```
...
:compileTestKotlin
w: /home/gorre/Workshop/kotlin-spring-boot-reactive/src/test/kotlin/io/shido/annotations/SpringWebFluxTest.kt: (18, 1): This annotation is deprecated in Kotlin. Use '@kotlin.annotation.Target' instead
w: /home/gorre/Workshop/kotlin-spring-boot-reactive/src/test/kotlin/io/shido/annotations/SpringWebFluxTest.kt: (20, 1): This annotation is deprecated in Kotlin. Use '@kotlin.annotation.Retention' instead
```

[image: Kotlin Annotation(s) error with Spring Boot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kotlin has it own `@kotlin.annotation.Retention` and `@kotlin.annotation.Target` annotations. take a while to look the [kotlin annotation documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotations) please.

### Edit

I have test it in springframework that no problem. Note that have a distinction in `@Target` between java and kotlin.

the kotlin `kotlin.annotation.@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)` is translated to:

```
@java.lang.annotation.Target(ElementType.TYPE);
```

and the kotlin `kotlin.annotation.@Target(AnnotationTarget.TYPE)` is translated to:

```
@java.lang.annotation.Target;
```

which means `AnnotationTarget.TYPE` don't supported for java. it just used in kotlin. so your own annotation should be like this:

```
//spring-test annotations
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = arrayOf("default", "test"))
@ContextConfiguration(classes = arrayOf(Application::class))
//spring-boot annotations
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
//kotlin annotations
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)// can remove it default is RUNTIME
annotation class SpringWebFluxTest;
```

Comment: I have them commented out in the example since that's the issue: I can't use them in the test class. It might be an issue with Spring (or not)...I have no clue. For now, I'm using the ones provided by Java (and getting the warnings) but I would like to use the Kotlin ones...that's the point for this question.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ okay. what wrong with you when using kotlin annotations?

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ sir, `AnnotationTarget.CLASS`  is equivalent to `ElementType.TYPE`. so you should replace `AnnotationTarget.TYPE` with `AnnotationTarget.CLASS` which just using type usage.

Comment: ...and you are right! I was using the same "type"! Silly! Thank you!